# Elements within dynamically created of <div> on each button click is not properly overridden

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a comment box where on each submit a new  is dynamically created. The inner elements of the `<div>` being 3 buttons Edit, Post, Cancel and a close icon(image). These are also dynamically created. I finally append them all together. The below code would generate something like the below image on two submits. The error I'm facing is that, whatever `<div>`'s close icon/button is clicked, always the last `<div>` is being affected. Here I tried to close 'Hi' but 'hello' is being affected.Also there is a duplication of the `<div>` on even comments.
 Kindly help me correct these issues.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comment</title>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="ta" rows="30" cols="30" readonly></textarea>
<br>
<input type="textbox" id="tb"></input><br>
<button onclick="add()">Submit</button><br>


<script type="text/javascript">


var newDiv="",i=1,ta="";
    function add() {
        i++;
        ta=document.getElementById('ta');
        newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.id = "d"+i;
        newDiv.style.display="block";

        newTa = document.createElement("input");
        newTa.type="text"
        newTa.id = "t"+i;
        //newTa.readonly='true';
        newTa.setAttribute("readOnly","true");
        newTa.style.display="block";

        newTa.onclick=function(){

        newP.style.visibility="visible";
        newImg.style.visibility="visible";
        newBut1.style.visibility="visible";
        newButt1.style.visibility="visible";

        };

       // document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {


        newP=document.createElement("BUTTON");
        newP.id="p"+i;
        newP.innerHTML="Edit";
        newP.style.visibility="hidden";
        newP.style.display="inline";
        newP.onclick=function()
        {



            newTa.removeAttribute('readonly'); // only needed the first time
            newTa.readOnly = false;

            //newTa.setAttribute("readOnly","false");
            //newTa.readonly='false';
            //newP.innerHTML="wrng";
        }

        newImg=document.createElement("IMG");
        newImg.id="i"+i;
        newImg.src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/close-icon-30.png";
        newImg.style.width="20%";
        newImg.style.height="20%";
        newImg.alt="close";
        newImg.style.visibility="hidden";
        newImg.style.display="inline";
        newImg.onclick=function()
        {
             newDiv.innerHTML="";
             //newDiv.remove();
        }

        newBut1=document.createElement("button");
        newBut1.id="b"+i;
        newBut1.innerHTML="Post";
        newBut1.style.visibility="hidden";
        newBut1.style.display="inline";
        newBut1.onclick=function(){
            //newTa.readonly='true';
            newTa.setAttribute("readOnly","true");
        }


        newButt1=document.createElement("button");
        newButt1.id="bt"+i;
        newButt1.innerHTML="Cancel";
        newButt1.style.visibility="hidden";

        newButt1.onclick=function(){
            newTa.value=document.getElementById('tb').value;
            newTa.readonly='true';
        }


        newDiv.appendChild(newTa);
        newDiv.appendChild(newP);
        newDiv.appendChild(newImg);
        newDiv.appendChild(newBut1);
        newDiv.appendChild(newButt1);


        var b=""
        b="t"+i;
        ta.appendChild(newDiv);
        document.getElementById(b).value=document.getElementById('tb').value;

    }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yow will need to use closure for that.

Comment: Thanks it works...I have another issue now. On even comments, there is a duplication of the <div>.How could I resolve this pls?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I have changed textarea to div.
Initial i to 0 instead of 1. You can also set it to 1. It won't affect the functionality.
Some variables were global, I have changed them to local variable now like newDiv,newP, newImg etc.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comment</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--<textarea id="ta" rows="30" cols="30" readonly></textarea>-->
<div id="ta"></div>
<br>
<input type="textbox" id="tb"></input><br>
<button onclick="add()">Submit</button><br>


<script type="text/javascript">


var i=0,ta="";
    function add() {
        (function(){
            i++;
        var temp_i = i;
        ta=document.getElementById('ta');
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.id = "d"+temp_i;
        newDiv.style.display="block";

        newTa = document.createElement("input");
        newTa.type="text"
        newTa.id = "t"+temp_i;
        //newTa.readonly='true';
        newTa.setAttribute("readOnly","true");
        newTa.style.display="block";

        newTa.onclick=function(){
        console.log(temp_i);
        console.log(i);
        newP.style.visibility="visible";
        newImg.style.visibility="visible";
        newBut1.style.visibility="visible";
        newButt1.style.visibility="visible";

        };

       // document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {


        var newP=document.createElement("BUTTON");
        newP.id="p"+temp_i;
        newP.innerHTML="Edit";
        newP.style.visibility="hidden";
        newP.style.display="inline";
        newP.onclick=function()
        {



            newTa.removeAttribute('readonly'); // only needed the first time
            newTa.readOnly = false;

            //newTa.setAttribute("readOnly","false");
            //newTa.readonly='false';
            //newP.innerHTML="wrng";
        }

        var newImg=document.createElement("IMG");
        newImg.id="i"+temp_i;
        newImg.src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/close-icon-30.png";
        newImg.style.width="20%";
        newImg.style.height="20%";
        newImg.alt="close";
        newImg.style.visibility="hidden";
        newImg.style.display="inline";
        newImg.onclick=function()
        {
             newDiv.innerHTML="";
             //newDiv.remove();
        }

        var newBut1=document.createElement("button");
        newBut1.id="b"+temp_i;
        newBut1.innerHTML="Post";
        newBut1.style.visibility="hidden";
        newBut1.style.display="inline";
        newBut1.onclick=function(){
            //newTa.readonly='true';
            newTa.setAttribute("readOnly","true");
        }


        var newButt1=document.createElement("button");
        newButt1.id="bt"+temp_i;
        newButt1.innerHTML="Cancel";
        newButt1.style.visibility="hidden";

        newButt1.onclick=function(){
            newTa.value=document.getElementById('tb').value;
            newTa.readonly='true';
        }


        newDiv.appendChild(newTa);
        newDiv.appendChild(newP);
        newDiv.appendChild(newImg);
        newDiv.appendChild(newBut1);
        newDiv.appendChild(newButt1);


        var b=""
        b="t"+temp_i;
        ta.appendChild(newDiv);
        document.getElementById(b).value=document.getElementById('tb').value;

        })();

    }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you specify which div is duplicate on even comments?

Comment: All the even comments create two copies of <div>(newDiv).Eg.If I cmt  'Hi' 1st followed by a second cmt "hello",I get Hi /n Hello /n Hello(duplicate) instead of one 'hi' /n 'hello'.

Comment: You will need to post the code, what happen when user click on post button. Currently it is not there.

Comment: I have updated the code. There were some bugs in that. Check if above problem is also fixed ( I haven't worked on it but might get fixed).

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use jquery to minimize your code campaign. Below is the code which will fix your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comment</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<div class="container">
<input type="textbox" id="tb"><br>

<button>Edit</button><button>Post</button><button class="cancel">Cancel</button><br />
</div>

<button class="submit">Submit</button><br>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.submit').click(function() {
        var element = '<div class="container">'+'<input type="textbox" id="tb"><br>'+
'<button>Edit</button><button>Post</button><button class="cancel">Cancel</button><br /></div>';
        $('.submit').before(element);
    });
    $('body').delegate('.cancel', 'click', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks